# Pure JS interactive text size buttons

Tags: javascript, onclick, closures

I run into this issue when browsing on MDN. I am trying to understand why scripts B and C are not working.

HTML:

```
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<h1>some heading 1 text</h1>
<h2>some heading 2 text</h2>

<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

A] JS script that is working OK ↓↓↓

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '12px';
};
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '14px';
};
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '16px';
};
```

B] JS script that IS NOT working ↓↓↓

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

C] JS script that IS ALSO NOT working ↓↓↓

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12);
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = makeSizer(14);
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = makeSizer(16);
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ/7726/

Comment: `var size12 = function () { makeSizer(12); }`. Or `.onclick = function () { makeSizer(12); } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that B] is not working is that when you do `var size12 = makeSizer(12);` it will **not actually assign** function makeSizer(with size attribute 12) to size12 but **it actually calls makeSizer(12)** and store the response of that function(which in this case undefined as function return nothing).

Same thing happen in C] as well it will assign `undefined` to onclick.

To achieve what you want, you can do following.

```js
var makeSizer=function(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size+'px';
    //console.log(size);
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function(){makeSizer(12);}
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = function(){makeSizer(14);}
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = function(){makeSizer(16);}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<h1>some heading 1 text</h1>
<h2>some heading 2 text</h2>

<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```